# iReport doesn't work on Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: java, report

iReport version 5.1 doesn't work on Windows 8 64-bit.

What do I do in this case?

On Windows 7, it works fine.

Comment: Try compatibility mode.

Comment: don't work man, =[, on xp sp3, windows vista, windows 7 compat. mode

Comment: Why don't you ask [the Jaspersoft community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer/answers)...

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of the underlying Netbeans platform, which violates one of the stricter Java 8 security rules. It has been fixed in Netbeans 7.4, but iReport has not been updated yet.

See this bug report for technical details: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229191

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works. I'm using iReport 5.6 on Windows 8.1 x64.
What doesn't work is iReport with JDK/JRE 8.
So, you need to install a previous JDK/JRE (JDK 1.7 u45 in my case) and either run using the following command:

```
[iReport DIR]\bin>ireport --jdkhome="[YOUR JDK/JRE home]"
```

or change the ireport.conf file located in `[iReport DIR]\etc`:

```
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

to

```
jdkhome="[YOUR JDK/JRE home]"
```

in my case:

```
jdkhome="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"
```

Comment: This field is in the report.conf file under `etc/` as well.